# MySQL not updating single field in database while updating others

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework 1.10.8 and MySQL Server 5.1.X.  I create my data array to update the record but only one field updates.

```
<?php 
    $where = "`character_id` = '5'";
    $healthGained = 5;
    $data = array();
    if ($healthGained > 0) {
        $data['character_current_health'] = $character['character_max_health'] + $healthGained;
        $data['character_max_health'] = $character['character_max_health'] + $healthGained;
        print_r($data);
        $characterInfoTable->update($data, $where);
    }
?>
```

What I get from the print_r is this:

Array
(
    [character_current_health] => 430
    [character_max_health] => 430
)

However the value of character_current_health does not change in the database.  The value of character_max_health does however.  Anyone know what is going on with this?

NOTE: The fields are named correctly and are the correct data type.  This is running on a Linux server running Ubuntu.

Comment: More details please. What field type is `character_current_health`?

Comment: One comment to your where clause, is there any reason for passing 5 as a string literal rather than an integer?

Comment: @kovshenin it doesn't matter in mySQL, it will be automatically cast to the field's type. It's largely regarded good practice in order to avoid SQL errors on non-numeric and null values (although arguably, those should get caught before)

Comment: @Pekka, I didn't say that's the error, yeah, best practices. Besides, if you remove the quotes from 5 you can single-quote the whole `character_id = 5` string literal, and single quotes are parsed faster than double quotes :-P I think.. ~ Every nanosecond counts ~

Comment: Use the Zend_Db_Profiler or tell MySQL to log your queries and see what is query is being generated.

Comment: @David Caunt: UPDATE `character_info` SET `character_level` = ?, `character_current_health` = ?, `character_max_health` = ?, `character_strength` = ?, `character_agility` = ?, `character_vitality` = ?, `character_iq` = ?, `character_current_magic` = ?, `character_max_magic` = ?, `character_current_energy` = ?, `character_max_energy` = ? WHERE (`character_id` = '5726b643-f866-47f0-b89d-78102fe13acf')Array
(
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 737
    [3] => 737
    [4] => 63
    [5] => 36
    [6] => 54
    [7] => 35
    [8] => 448
    [9] => 448
    [10] => 1404
    [11] => 1404
)

Answer (score 0):

Geeez!  Nevermind.  I am an idiot sometimes.  It was updating correctly but due to a poor flow of operations, I re-updated the table with the wrong value.

Comment: So often the cause of these 'weird' errors. When something like this happens it's hard to debug until you give up all your assumptions!